# Cygwin linking error for _ftime

Tags: cygwin, linker-errors, undefined-reference

When trying to link some older code with customized Windows/POSIX portability, there are `#ifdef` conditional compilations that call `_ftime()` on Cygwin and `ftime()` everywhere else (note the leading `_`).

When I try to compile and link this code, though, I get the following

```
../../bin/../lib/libconv-core.a(convcore.o):convcore.c:(.text+0xf6b): undefined reference to `_ftime'
../../bin/../lib/libconv-core.a(convcore.o):convcore.c:(.text+0xf6b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_ftime'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found that present Cygwin actually defines the common POSIX function `ftime()`. Just call it by its standard name instead of the Microsoft CRT oddity.